# MS Sql Server performance UPDATEing a single column vs all columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

MS SQL Srvr 2005/2008 on Win Srvr 2003+

I am only updating 1 row at a time, the UPDATE is in response to a user change on a web form.

I am updating a few columns in a table using the PK.  The table has 95 columns.  Typically 1 FK column and 1 or 2 other columns will be updated. The table has 6 FK's.

Is it of benefit for me to dynamically generate the UPDATE statement only having the columns being changed in the SET portion of the UPDATE, or stick with the current Stored Procedure using a parameterized update with all of the columns?

Currently, and not subject to immediate change, the data from the web form is posted back to the server and is available for the update.  I can't jump to an AJAX scenario where only changed data is posted back to the server from the client browser at this point.

Thanx,
G

Comment: [This issue is looked at here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith: That's a different issue.  This question is about whether you can optimize by updating only the columns that have changed.  The article you link to talks about an update that doesn't perform any changes at all.

Comment: @Andomar - Yep actually is a  different issue but still pretty relevant and the OP can use the techniques from there to check for themself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server reads and writes "pages" that consist of 8kb of data.  Typically, a page will contain one or more row.

Since disk I/O is the expensive part of an update, the cost of updating half the columns and all the columns is roughly the same.  It will still result in 8kb disk I/O.

There's another aspect, that usually doesn't come into play because SQL Server writes in 8kb pages.  But imagine your row looks like this:

```
id int identity
col1 varchar(50)
col2 varchar(50)
```

Now if you update `col1` to be 5 bytes longer, `col2` has to be moved forward by five bytes.  So even if you don't update `col2`, it will still have to be written to disk.

Comment: And my table has this varchar issue too.  
At this point, we'll stay with the practice of updating all columns.  
I've come to this decision from 
- reading the suggestions from @MartinSmith pointing me to Paul_White blog, 
- and Andomars sage advice regarding disk I/O cost, 
- plus another friends advice about the complexity and processing time spent making the query dynamic, 
- notes on caching the queryplan when using the same update statement each time.  
Much appreciated, thank you gentlepersons.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance its better to update multiple columns in a single update than updating single columns in multiple updates, once the databases locks a row for updating the time used for changing the values is not a performance issue, on the other hand the time that takes to lock a row can cause performance issues and it can get worst if you have multiple connections trying to access the same information. I would recommend to stay as you are with the parameterized stored procedure rather than trying to update single row-columns.